# PHP to CSV not outputting fields correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output my PHP code to a downloadable CSV file and so far i am able to do this however at the moment, the output does not place the field data into separate columns. Instead it puts everything into one column and in addition to that, it displays the postcodes in its neighbouring columns. Does anyone know why this is?

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv");  
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"');  

$outstream = fopen("php://output",'w');  

if ($db_found) {

// Select all fields from bodyshops_master_network table
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM bodyshops_master_network";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    // Splits the arrays
    $row = explode(",", $db_field['postcodes_covered']);

        $dealer_code = $db_field['dealer_code'];
        $dealer_name = $db_field['dealer_name'];
        $bodyshop_id = $db_field['bodyshop_id'];
        $bodyshop_name = $db_field['bodyshop_name'];
        $address1 = $db_field['address1'];
        $address2 = $db_field['address2'];
        $address3 = $db_field['address3'];
        $address4= $db_field['address4'];
        $address5 = $db_field['address5'];
        $postcode = $db_field['postcode'];
        $bo_tel = $db_field['BO_tel'];
        $bo_email = $db_field['BO_email'];
        $bc_name = $db_field['BC_name'];
        $equity_contract = $db_field['equity_contract'];

    echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {

        echo $dealer_code . " ";
        echo $dealer_name . " ";
        echo $bodyshop_id . " ";
        echo $bodyshop_name . " ";
        echo $address1 . " ";
        echo $address2 . " ";
        echo $address3 . " ";
        echo $address4 . " ";
        echo $address5 . " ";
        echo $postcode . " ";
        echo $bo_tel . " ";
        echo $bo_email . " ";
        echo $bc_name . " ";
        echo $equity_contract . " ";
        echo $value. "<BR>";

       fputcsv($outstream, $row, ',', '"');  
    }
        echo "</pre>";

}

mysql_close($db_handle);

} else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
fclose($outstream);  
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your output is? I can't work out how you'd ever get anything apart from the postcode in the CSV file.

Comment: Also, this looks like a really bad database structure. You really should have postcodes in a separate table with a foreign key in the `bodyshops_master_network` table.

Comment: My output is all the data fields echoed in the foreach loop and the postcodes however, it doesn't put them into separate columns. For example: http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Screenshot2013-11-20at090759_zpsf1d90fc5.png.

Comment: Open the resulting CSV in a **text editor** and show us what that looks like.

Comment: All the fields are just dumped into the first column and should be in separate columns because they are different data fields. In addition, the postcodes (ST16, ST17, ST18 ... etc) should be displayed vertically in rows as opposed to horizontally

Comment: @deceze i have added a link to the image in my previous comment

Comment: Not a screenshot from how it looks in Excel (or whatever that is), a sample of the plain text CSV file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you're doing something really weird here. You're outputting content in two ways.

First, you output content in the normal way using `echo`. Fair enough!

Second, you output content using `fputcsv` where the file handler leads to `php://output`. Also fair enough!

But you shouldn't do both and expect it to work seamlessly. You want a CSV file, so the best way is to output all your data using `fputcsv`. At the moment, some of your data is encapsulated as a CSV file, and some of it isn't. This leads to output that you don't really want.

I *think* you want something like this:

```
foreach ($row as $value) {
    $output = array(
       $dealer_code,
       $dealer_name,
       $bodyshop_id,
       $bodyshop_name,
       $address1,
       $address2,
       $address3,
       $address4,
       $address5,
       $postcode,
       $bo_tel,
       $bo_email,
       $bc_name.
       $equity_contract,
       $value
   );

   fputcsv($outstream, $output, ',', '"');  
}
```

`fputcsv` expects the data to be an array, so that's what we give it. The separate array fields will be separate columns in the CSV output. We don't `echo` any data: we store it in an array and then supply it to `fputcsv`.

The second mistake you made was to send `$row` rather than `$value` to `fputcsv`. This meant that you were sending all the postcodes as received from the database row.

Finally, you don't need `<pre>`.

On a separate note, you *really* should have a better database structure. If you had a table of postcodes and a *separate* table of bodyshops and a foreign key linking them, the code to retrieve data would be a lot simpler, as would searching and updating it in future.

Comment: That makes sense as to why my output was weird. Thank you!